# Использование EF Core в сложной модели БД

Tags: c#, база-данных, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-core

Предположим, есть столбец `X`, который хранит `Id` разных моделей в зависимости от столбца `Y`.

Следовательно, навигационное свойство для `X` не имеет заранее определенного типа.

Как построить `LINQ` запрос для выполнения на стороне БД?

Хотелось бы как-то указать `EF Core`, что если `Y` в диапазоне `0..10`, то должно подгружаться модель `A` в навигационное свойство `X` и т.д.

Таблица полиморфных моделей не подходит т.к. модели не должны быть наследованы.

ОБНОВЛЕНО:

Хочу использовать для хранения событий: получилось немного грязно, но работает. Если объект `Event`, который хранит инфо о событии и `Id` объекта на которым произошло событие, а в остальных моделях хранится Id последнего события.
Вот пример запроса:

```
predicate = predicate.And(e => 
   dbContext.Videos.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Id == e.ObjectId) != null &&
   dbContext.Videos.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Id == e.ObjectId).Code == self.Code);
```

Comment: Для начала расскажите как вы такой хитрый внешний ключ умудрились создать в базе, что он сразу на несколько таблиц указывает...

Comment: Какой тип связи используется для ``X``? Или там тупо числа на абы-какую таблицу в БД?

Comment: в поле просто число, используется 1 к 1.

Comment: обновил @PavelMayorov

Comment: @Winston вы предоставляете неоднозначные данные, чтобы разобраться - нужна модель всех затрагиваемых таблиц в БД.